# Custom 240V Infrared Heater Controller

Tags: arduino, solid-state-relay, dimmer, heater

I'm DIY'ing a controller for a few heaters I'm placing on my covered deck, components listed below. I'm using an Arduino Uno Wifi Rev2 to control on/off and a dimmer to adjust the heater output.

A 240V / 16A infrared heater will be powered via a 10 gauge circuit running from a double pole 20 amp breaker. Before hitting the heater I'll have one hot line go through an SSR and then to a leading edge dimmer. My understanding is I should be able to have the other hot wire go directly to the heater.

**Question:** Is this an acceptable approach?

**Diagram**
[image]

**Components**

- [Heater](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M06TZ6P)
- [SSR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09GLRRGLT)
- [Dimmer](https://www.tindie.com/products/bugrovs2012/pwm-16a-3500w-triac-leading-edge-dimmer-50hz-60hz/?fbclid=IwAR15XnUtXgYGOimH7QmIIQBkSh7aXAmVPKrtP6XKYbgFkk8tTrrdv-Fg8-w)
- [Arduino Uno Wifi Rev2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MK598QV)
- [Rotary Encoder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07T3672VK)

Comment: Hi there! What is the second question?

Comment: Removed it, I think the dimmer is WAI after chatting with some other folks.